# How mimic the function map.getORelse to a CSV file

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a CSV file that represent a map[String,Int], then I am reading the file as follows:

```
def convI2N (vkey:Int):String={

    val in = new Scanner("dictionaryNV.csv")
    loop.breakable{
    while (in.hasNext) {
      val nodekey = in.next(',')
      val value  = in.next('\n')
      if (value == vkey.toString){
        n=nodekey
        loop.break()}
    }}
    in.close
    n
  }
```

the function give the String given the Int. The problem here is that I must browse the whole file, and the file is to big, then the procedure is too slow. Someone tell me that this is O(n) complexity time, and recomend me to pass to O(log n). I suppose that the function map.getOrElse is O(log n).
Someone can help me to find a way to get a best performance of this code?

As additional comment, the dictionaryNV file is sorted by the Int values
maybe I can divide the file by lines, or set of lines. The CSV has like 167000 Tuples [String,Int]

or in another way how you make some kind of binary search through the csv in scala?

Comment: Are you trying to look up the key from a value?  Map[String,Int] lets you look up an Int given a String, not the other way around.  What makes you say that  "map.getOrElse is O(log n)"?

Comment: Any reason you can't just load the whole file into a Map in memory once then do all of your lookups from that map instead of going to the file each time?

Comment: Someone told me that map.getOrElse is O(log n), but i just want to corroborate, the program has another operations that overload the memory, that is the reason to not load the file in memory

Comment: or in another way how you make some kind of binary search through the csv in scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `confI2N` function many times then definitely the job will be slow because each time you have to `scan` the `big file`. So if the function is called many times then it is recommended to store them in temporary variable as `properties` or `hashmap` or `collection of tuple2` and change the other code that is eating the memory.

You can try following way which should be faster than `scanner` way 
Assuming that your `csv` file is `comma` separated as

```
key1,value1
key2,value2
```

Using Source.fromFile can be your solution as

```
def convI2N (vkey:Int):String={
  var n = "not found"
  val filtered = Source.fromFile("<your path to dictionaryNV.csv>")
    .getLines()
    .map(line => line.split(","))
    .filter(sline => sline(0).equalsIgnoreCase(vkey.toString))

  for(str <- filtered){
    n = str(0)
  }
 n
}
```